# Dask threaded scheduler debug tips

Tags: python, dask

I'm working on a [binderhub-based notebook](https://github.com/pangeo-data/open-source-geoscience/pull/5) to run some examples for my library which uses dask and xarray. I've found that in certain situations/calculations the threaded scheduler will just hang and stop processing. I know about profiling, but since it hangs and I have to kill it I'm not sure if this is a viable option. I've also read through the debugging information [here](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/debugging.html), but the logging information seems to be for distributed or multiprocess schedulers. The calculations are best run on a threaded scheduler and some operations are not multiprocess-safe. The notebook works fine locally which makes it harder to debug this.

Does anyone have any other ideas how I can debug this?

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen the threaded scheduler deadlock on its own.  My first guess would be that your functions are sensitive somehow to running with others.

To debug you might consider printing out the set of currently running tasks at each transition.  This might help you to identify a pattern about when your system deadlocks.  For this you might look at [custom callbacks](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/diagnostics-local.html#custom-callbacks)